# Cleanest way of checking if any of 5 variables exist in params, change a different table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 models, a company, and an event. I would like to track how the companies team_size and valuation changes at each event, so, I decided to add a company_team_size and a company_valuation field to the events table. Whenever the team is updated, I am trying to check if the team_size or valuation are part of the updates params, and if so, update the most recent event in the events table.

Something like:

```
def update
  #other code 
  if params[:company_team_size] || params[:company_valuation] 
  @event = @company.latest_event(params)
  #Write values into event db 
  end
end
```

Here's my question. What is the most efficient way to check for all of these params (let's say I wanted to add 5 more) without making my code a mess? Making 3 line if statements like

```
if params[:column]
  @event.column = params[:column]
end`
```

is relatively gross (but what I have now), but feels marginally wasteful as I'm already checking if it exists in the params. I also want to check for all of the params in 1 if for readability, unless I could make all of them one liners, like.

```
#Keep track of these over-time
@event.column = params[column] if params[column]
@event.column2 = params[column2] if params[column2]
```

etc. When I tried testing this in repl.it, I couldn't tell if @event.column was being set to nil if params[column] was false, or if it wasn't setting anything for the @event.column variable. Would this instantiate the variable, and overwrite what's in the events table?

This is a inconsequential question, but I'm a bit curious what's under the hood with Ruby, and this is the question that got me to start wondering. AIA.

Comment: Do you want to check if they exist, or if they're not blank? What if `params[column] = ''`?

Comment: @Schwern I want to check if they exist. They *shouldn't* be able to be sent as a blank value.

Comment: There's the S word. So you only want non-blank values?

Comment: @Schwern Doesn't matter if they're blank. If those keys are included in the update, I want to write their value to a different table (the events table, when the company is being updated). But, I'm saying I'm not sure if the value of event.column = params[column] if params[column] would be nil, or if event.column just wouldn't be assigned to anything. I'm assuming if event.column was being set to nil, and I called event.save, it would update the event database with that nil value, even if the param isn't there.

Comment: If `params[column]` is nil, `event.column = params[column] if params[column]` will not run and `event.column` is unmodified. Same as `a = 42 if false` will not set `a` to 42.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way to do this. Use nested attributes.

```
class Company
  has_many :events

  # new and update accept an extra events_attributes hash
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true
end

class CompanyController
  def update
    ...

    # Because Company accepts_nested_attributes_for Events
    # this will update, add, and delete @company.events as well
    # as updating @company.
    # Adds will not have an event ID.
    # Updates will have an event ID.
    # Deletes will have an event ID and a special flag.
    @company.update!(company_params)

    ...
  end

private
  def company_params
    params
      .require(:company)
      .permit(:id, :some, :company, :attributes,
        event_attributes: [:id, :some, :event, :attributes]
      )
  end
```

See [Building Complex Forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) and [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for).

---

Use [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-slice) to get just the parameters you're interested in.

```
EVENT_PARAMS = [:foo, :bar, :baz].freeze

private def event_params
  params.slice(EVENT_PARAMS)
end
```

Use [`attributes=`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-attributes-3D) to bulk update multiple attributes.

```
@event.attributes = event_params
```

Then one can filter the parameters. Filtering the params depends on whether you want to check for the key existing at all, any non-nil value, or a non-blank ("present") value.

- `param[:column] = nil`   # :column exists
- `param[:column] = ' '`   # :column is blank
- `param[:column] = 'foo'` # :column is present

> They shouldn't be able to be sent as a blank value.

Of course they can. Anyone can send you anything they want.

Most of the time you want only the present values. Use the convenience method [`compact_blank`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-compact_blank) to filter only parameters with non-blank values.

```
@event.attributes = event_params.compact_blank
```